# PayPal once in a while does not redirect to our page 1 out 1000

Tags: paypal

I use PayPal Express Checkout for our web site.  It works most of the time; however, one out of a thousand times, PayPal does not redirect to our page although the transaction went through PayPal.  I sometimes get a timeout on calling DoExpressCheckout after receiving a redirect from PayPal.  This is not good since the customer paid, but not get recorded to our database because we never receive the redirect from PayPal or DoExpressCheckout call timed out.  Does anyone have similar problem?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your server. You say that Paypal does redirect, but the problem is that you sometimes get a timeout on calling DoExpressCheckout. Mind posting the relevant code showing how you're handling this process?

Comment: That timed out problem only happened once.  The non-redirect problem is the one that I am concern with.  Basically I call expresscheck out classic Api setting a return Url as our page.  After the user pays on paypal,  our page doesn't get invoked.

Comment: Please show some code on how you are currently doing this. Is this IPN?

Comment: If the money is actually moving into your account then the DECP call must have completed.  The money doesn't move until that call is done, so your problem must be AFTER that call is made.  If it was timing out that call wouldn't complete and you wouldn't end up with the money.